# Как настроить unordered_map в STL для C++, так чтобы среднее время работы было минимальным?

Tags: c++, stl, хеширование, unordered-map

В частности, есть `unordered_map <int, vector <int> >`, ключ изменяется от 1 до 10^9, общее количество элементов 10^5, каждый элемент имеет свой ключ и кладется в соответствующий этому ключу вектор. В документации к *unordered_map* есть функции
 `max_load_factor`
 `rehash`
 `reserve`

Как с их помощью настроить максимальную скорость добавления и поиска? Ограничение по используемой памяти 200 Mb

Comment: мне кажется вы смотрите малость не в ту сторону(точнее слишком узко)... если вы знаете всё о ваших данных, вы вполне можете написать идеальную хэш функцию. Памяти у вас не так чтобы мало - можете сделать в вашем map побольше свободного места на старте. Что касается вектора, в нём скорее всего стоит хранить элементы отсортированными(если собираетесь искать не меньше чем вставлять), это сделает поиск немного быстрее, вставку немного медленнее

Comment: max_load_factor не то, метод является селектором и просто возвращает  установленный процент нагрузки каждого сегмента.  reserve  просто резервирует память, но не изменяет  контейнер .  А вот  . rehash  вполне подходит  при заранее известном количестве элементов, если это количество превышает  max_load_factor() * bucket_count() .  Метод  rehash  устанавливает количество сегментов для хранения элементов. Но, мне кажется, вам вовсе и не нужен  unordered_map